# How to create tabed pannel using struts 2

Tags: struts2

I was using this jsp And servlet for reporting But i want to develop same report using struts 2 how we can do it in that we need to create tabed pannel I am new to struts can you help me out ???????

Answer (score 0):

For creating a tabbed panel using struts 2 you can use struts2-jquery plugin. You will just need struts2-jquery.jar

http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/TabbedPanelTag